# Синонимизировать [crypto] и [криптография]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть метка [crypto](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crypto), по смыслу совершенно схожая с [криптография](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%8f). Предлагаю их синонимизировать в пользу [криптография](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%8f) (у неё описание есть и гораздо больше вопросов).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 39 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 37 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 33 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'crypto': [crypto] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 521
tag remapping of [криптография] and [crypto] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
3 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```

Comment: А где у вас вот это выводится?

Comment: @nchistov при объединении меток [такой попап](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtwZt.png) выводится для модераторов.

Comment: А я не модератор, и у меня в Teams выводится.

Comment: @Petəíŕd админ в тимс - тот же модератор

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ага, кажется, я что-то понял